# Condition for checking whether a letter is between 'j' and 'p'

Tags: c

The code should accept a character and it should check whether its between 'j' and 'p'.

If it is between 'j' and 'p' it should print `yes` or else it should print `no`.

I have tried to do something about it but the only ideas I got is this:

```
if (a=='j' || a=='k' || a=='k' || a=='l' || a=='m' || a=='n' || a=='o' || a=='p')
{
   printf("YES");
} 
else
{
   printf("NO");
}
```

Comment: sorry not using linux

Comment: read: `man ascii` or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html . Then think about how you would check if a `int` is a specific range or not.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 My Deathstation-9000 uses EBCDIC and this should run on it. :) (Though the approach you have in mind actually will, depending on how it's written)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Hence the parenthetical aside. Though using magic ASCII numbers like newbies are prone to do instead of character literals would break it.

Comment: @Shawn What is wrong with `'j'` and `'p'`? I never suggested that he should write the number as in a decimal notation. Note: `'j'` and `'p'` are both numbers of type `int`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Nothing is. But, like I mentioned, it's really common to see people *not* doing that in favor of 106 and 112. They usually eventually learn better practices, at least.

Comment: How would you check whether a number is between 1000000 and 2000000? Write down a million comparisons?

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid all the alternative tests by using a function like [`strchr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr):

```c
if (strchr("jklmnop", a)) {
    puts("YES");
} else {
   puts("NO");
}
```

---

The obvious approach is to do something like

```c
if (a >= 'j' && a <= 'p') {
    // ...
}
```

but that has a problem if you want to write portable code.

The C standard only requires that the characters `'0'` through `'9'` appear consecutively and in order. If you're following the standard to a t, you shouldn't assume that `'j'` through `'p'` appear together and can be used with a pair of `>=` and `<=` tests. If you add additional qualifications like requiring an ASCII compatible character set, it's a different story.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Yes, that is how I usually write code to check to see if a character is one of a small set. And are you dissing One True Brace style? Heathen.

Comment: This does not check whether the character is *between* two characters. This checks whether a character is *in a set*. This may or may not mean the same thing, depending on your encoding. Your method also requires memorising the alphabet, and checking whether your set correctly represents a range requires mental effort.

Comment: And I think it's obvious that between the letters j and p refers to the English alphabet, not random character encodings. An ideal answer would work with any encoding that has those letters in it, no matter where they are in it.

Comment: @Shawn YES. Your style is horrible, sorry. The `{` and `}` mark a block, the code inside is separate from the code outside, this is how the computer sees it and the style should visually represent that. But with your style, halve of the code that is logically inside `{` and `}` is visually outside, even worse some of the characters are visually halve inside and outside. Don't believe me? Draw a line between `{` and `}`.  The `{` and `}` belong together, they should always be on the same horizontal or vertical line.

Comment: And English is not everybody's default language. Some people have e.g. ó right after o, others have ö after o, and still others have `j k l ly m n ny o ó ö ő p q`. I don't know of an existing encoding that encode the characters in any of these orders, but such encodings are not prohibited by the standard.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 There are several indentation styles (read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_1TBS_(OTBS)) and which one is horrible or not is just a matter of taste.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It's pretty clear from OP's efforts what alphabet is being used for the problem and what characters are desired to be included.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The Computer makes a logical block between `{` and `}`, a style that does not represent that is horrible.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 tell that the millions of programmers that use the OTB indent style. Personally I don't like OTB style either, but as I wrote before, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: You should stop with the criticism of the brace style; it is not suitable for comments and is, regardless of your beliefs, a matter of opinion unless you have scientific studies demonstrating that humans make more or fewer errors with one or the other or demonstrating other measurable objective effects.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: with 1TBS, beginners will never write `for (i = 0; i < n; i++); { some code }`

Comment: `if (strchr("jklmnop", a))` is not equivalent to `if (a >= 'j' && a <= 'p')` even with ASCII encoding.  One should write `if (a > 0 && a <= UCHAR_MAX && strchr("jklmnop", a))` which is not really elegant.

Comment: This is a fine answer.  Why is everybody ripping it to shreds?  Is it nitpick-a-random-answer-to-death day today, and I forgot?

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm used to 90's era comp.lang.c levels of pedantry here on SO, and am obviously guilty of it myself, but I really didn't expect someone to question what 'between' means. Or complain about having to know the alphabet. Or draw imaginary lines on the screen and complain about the patterns they make. Weird day to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "between j and p".

If you mean "Only lowercase English letters between j and p", then one portable way of writing it down is

```
if (strchr("jklmnop", a)) ...
```

If you mean "Character codes between that of `'j'` and that of `'p'`, in whatever encoding is used by the machine", then one portable way of writing it down is

```
if (a >= 'j' && a <= 'p') ...
```

If your encoding is ASCII, then the two notions above strictly coincide for any range of English letters.

If your encoding is EBCDIC, then they coincide for the range `j..p`, but not say for the range `i..p`.

It is guaranteed that all English letters between j and p are included in the range of the codes in any standards-compliant encoding, but there might be additional, non-English-letter characters in the same range.

Finally, for completeness, if by "between j and p" you mean "letters of the user's language, whatever it is, that are between j and p", then one correct way of writing it down is *probably*

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, ""); // first statement of the program

...
if (strcoll(a, "j") >= 0 && strcoll(a, "p") <= 0) ...
```

Note that here, `a` is not a character as above, but a *string*. It is up to you to ensure that it contains a single *character* of the user's language (which is not the same thing as a single `char` element). Ensuring this is *very* non-trivial.

---

TL;DR

`if (a >= 'j' && a <= 'p')` will *probably* work for whatever task you currently have, but don't assume it will always work.

Comment: For `strcoll`, you would have to convert the character in `a` to a string first, and that might be a multi-byte sequence, or you might have to use `wcscoll`, depending on the operating environment.

Comment: Even if `a` is a `char` or an `unsigned char`, you should check that `a != 0` in addition to `if (strchr("jklmnop", a))` or possibly use `if (memchr("jklmnop", a, 7))`

Comment: @chqrlie good point

Answer (score 0):

Each and every alphabet has an ASCII code which is an integer so you can perform it like this,

```
char a;
scanf("%c",&a);
if(a>='j'&&a<='p')
{
    printf("YES");
}
else
{
    printf("NO");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a;
    printf("enter the letter :");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if(a>='j'  && a<='p')
    printf("yes the letter is between j and p");
    else
    printf("No the given letter is not between j and p");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lowercase letters form a contiguous block in the execution set, which is true for ASCII, you can write:

```
if (a >= 'j' && a <= 'p') ...
```

Assuming `a` is an `int` containing a `char` value, You can write this as a single test, but a good compiler should be able to generate the same code for the more readable test above:

```
if ((unsigned)(a - 'j') <= (unsigned)('p' - 'j')) ...
```

You could also test if `a` is in a set of characters, which will work regardless of the target encoding:

```
if (a != 0 && strchr("jklmnop", a)) ...
```

The test for `a != 0` can be removed if you know `a` cannot be a null byte.

Answer (score -3):

Character literals (This is a character literal: `'a'`) are just numbers. Almost all computers use a ASCII-compatible encoding (there are very few exceptions).
ASCII assumed, for example `'a'` is a `97` for your computer, `'j'` a `106`. if you write `a=='j'` you basically write `a==106`. Using character literals is just syntax sugar, it makes it a lot easier for humans to read but the computer does not care.

This means, you have to check if `a` is between `106` and `112`. You probably know a better way to do that than you current way. But instead of `106` and `112` write `'j'` and `'p'`, because it easier to read.